# ¿Por qué Android Studio está "ignorando" lo que tengo en mi archivo .gitignore?

Tags: android-studio, git, github, gitignore

Al principio de mi proyecto escribí esto en `.gitignore`

```
/build
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
*.json
/app/fabric.properties
```

En la penúltima línea yo indicaba que ignorase **todos los archivos `.json`**, cosa que hacía. Cuando yo hago un commit, todos los `.json` son ignorados.

Luego, yo tuve la necesidad de algunos archivos `.json` en la carpeta `raw` de mi proyecto, y quería que esos archivos sean subidos a Github. Para ello añadí esta directiva en `.gitignore`: **`!raw/*.json`**. A mi entender, esto ignoraría **todos los archivos `.json` excepto los que están en la carpeta `raw`**.

Mi `.gitignore` está así ahora:

```
/build
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
*.json
!raw/*.json
/app/fabric.properties
```

Sin embargo, no me está funcionando. Cuando subo un commit, los `.json` son ignorados, también los de la carpeta `raw`. Y observo que cuando creo un `.json` nuevo en esa carpeta, se pone en gris (signo de que no se subirá), cuando creo un archivo "subible", como una clase u otro, se pone en verde. Para que un nuevo `.json` se suba, tengo que hacer clic derecho sobre él y seleccionar `Add`.

Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué Android Studio está "ignorando" mi nuevo archivo `.gitignore`? ¿Es mi directiva la que está mal? ¿Tengo que resetar algo a nivel de git para que asuma la nueva directiva?

Comment: Quizás tenga que ver con un detalle que se menciona en la documentación "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded." (No es posible re-incluir un fichero si una carpeta padre de ese fichero está excluida)

Comment: @abulafia pero aquí no se cumple ese caso, pues la carpeta `raw` no está excluida, de hecho, en `raw` yo tengo otros archivos con extensión `.txt` que sí son subidos, el problema a mi entender es que Android Studio se quedó ignorando los archivos `.json` (configuración inicial) y no me reconoce la nueva directiva, o que esa directiva está mal, no sé ...

Comment: Puedes poner en línea de comandos `git status` y ver si en la salida te aparecen esos .jsones o ni los menciona. Si no los menciona es git quien los está ignorando, y Android Studio no tendría nada qué ver

Comment: @abulafia al escribir  `git status` no me salen esos `.json`, es raro, porque ahí me salen archivos ignorados **en rojo**.

Comment: No, los archivos ignorados nunca salen en `git status` ni en rojo ni en ningún otro color. Los que te salen en rojo son los que tienes en tu carpeta _pero nunca has añadido al repositorio_, es decir, los que **tú** estás ignorando, pero git no los ignora y de hecho te avisa (en rojo) de que debes hacer algo con ellos, ya sea meterlos al repo, o listarlos en el .gitignore para que no molesten más

Comment: @abulafia es cierto, me sale `Archivos sin seguimiento` y a continuación dos archivos que no están en el ignore. Voy a probar a meter uno de esos en `.gitignore`

Comment: He metido uno de esos archivos al ignore y no los ignora. Yo creo que no me está reconociendo mi archivo ignore. ¿Sabes si hay que resetar o algo y cómo se hace @abulafia?

Comment: Quizás no estás editando el .gitignore correcto. Prueba en línea de comandos `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` y te mostrará la ruta al "top-level" de tu repo. El fichero . gitignore ha de estar en esa carpeta.

Comment: @abulafia me muestra el directorio raíz de mi proyecto de Android Studio y es ese archivo `.gitignore` el que estoy modificando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que describes es mas o menos correcto pero es importante primero definir que ignore todo el directorio y posteriormente agregar la excepción.

Lo que podemos entender por la documentación relacionada a `.gitignore` es esto, aunque en realidad no funciona correctamente:

```
#Ignora todo el contenido del directorio /raw
raw/*

#excepto los archivos .json contenidos dentro de /raw
!raw/*.json
```

**Para que funcione correctamente y puedas ignorar todo el directorio `/raw` excepto los archivos .json debes definir la ruta completa del directorio en ambos casos**:

```
#Ignora todo el contenido del directorio /raw
/myapp/src/main/res/raw/*

#excepto los archivos .json contenidos dentro de /raw
!/myapp/src/main/res/raw/*.json
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se tendría este resultado, ignoraría todos los archivos excepto los .json contenidos dentro de tu carpeta `/raw`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]